# How can you do a full system scan with ClamAV on Ubuntu only?

Tags: clamav

I have both Ubuntu and Windows on my computer and when I do a full system scan, it scans Windows files too (and first). Is there a way to scan all the files only on Ubuntu?

Comment: have you tried `clamscan -r /home` or `clamscan -r / `?

Comment: @ron Windows is probably mounted in /media/ or /mnt/.  Umounting the windows disk would be my 1st option though

Comment: @Rinzwind yes, first I thought that. Then thought this will be a bit easier to scan only Ubuntu

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Easily you have to exclude the windows partition

```
clamscan -rv --exclude=/path-to-mounting-point-of-windows-files
```

Or just unmount the windows disk

---

**Details**

Determine the windows disk/partition

```
sudo fdisk -l | grep NTFS
```

for example you'll get result such as

```
/dev/sdc1   *        2048  1953521663   976759808    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

Thus the disk/partition for windows is  /dev/sdc1.

Now you should determine what is the mounting point of this partition

```
mount | grep /dev/sdc1
```

The output would be like

```
/dev/sdc1 on /media/Windows type ext4 (rw)
```

Then the mounting point is /media/Windows

Now you can run the command again

```
clamscan -rv --exclude=/media/Windows
```

Comment: Thanks, I found the Windows folder and it worked, but I tried unmounting the Windows disk too and the second command wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

There is a GUI front end for clam av called [clamtk](https://code.google.com/p/clamtk/). Here is how to install:

**Terminal**:

```
wget https://bitbucket.org/dave_theunsub/clamtk/downloads/clamtk_5.18-1_all.deb
sudo dpkg -clamtk_5.18-1_all.deb
```

After that search for `clamtk` in the dash.

**GUI**

start up the Ubuntu Software centre, search for `clamtk`, and select which version you want to install:

[image]

**HOWTO**:

Double click on `Whitelist` and select where the Windows partition is mounted, and it will not scan that. Me personally, I white listed the `/mnt/` and `/media/` folder.

[image]

If you want to scan them you can do so manually. Double click `Scan a directory`, and select your partition or other drives.